# Как с помощью python получить размер файла на GoogleDisk не скачивая его

Tags: python, requests, download, urllib

Я скачиваю с GoogleDisk файл по его идентификатору '1-kGqVo_R6xwc2UeMWTnlhrOiB5SCbUam' и называю его blue_sea1.jpg

для этого у меня прекрасно работает вот такой код:

```
import requests
import urllib.request

def download_file_from_google_drive(id, destination):
    URL = "https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download"
    session = requests.Session()
    response = session.get(URL, params = { 'id' : id }, stream = True)
    token = get_confirm_token(response)
    if token:
        params = { 'id' : id, 'confirm' : token }
        response = session.get(URL, params = params, stream = True)

    save_response_content(response, destination)

    def get_confirm_token(response):
       for key, value in response.cookies.items():
          if key.startswith('download_warning'):
             return value

    return None

def save_response_content(response, destination):
     CHUNK_SIZE = 32768

    with open(destination, "wb") as f:
        for chunk in response.iter_content(CHUNK_SIZE):
            if chunk: # filter out keep-alive new chunks
                f.write(chunk)

 if __name__ == "__main__":
    file_id = '1-kGqVo_R6xwc2UeMWTnlhrOiB5SCbUam'
    destination = 'blue_sea1.jpg'
    download_file_from_google_drive(file_id, destination)
```

Вопрос: как получить размер этого же файла не скачивая его?

Comment: Ну по идее `response.headers['Content-Length']`, но не уверен, что `.get` уже не забирает сразу файл, а если делать `.head` вместо `.get`, то оно размер не отдаёт

Comment: Проверил. В response.headers информация о размере не содержится. Там много информации, только не то, что нужно.